# node_module import not using full path when compiled to js

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio

I'm currently trying to migrate a project to use TypeScript instead of Javascript but running into some issues getting imports from third party libraries working.

Specifically I'm trying to use
sweetalert2,
axios,
and chart.js

I've got everything I need setup in my typescript file and that looks fine (no compile issues etc)

```
// Root/wwwroot/ts/my_file.ts
import Swal from 'sweetalert2';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Chart, ChartItem } from 'chart.js';

...
```

I'm using Visual Studio to deal with the compiling

[image]

```
//tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl":  "./",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "outDir": "../js/",
    "lib": [
      "ES5",
      "ES2015",
      "DOM",
      "ScriptHost"
    ],
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "moduleResolution":  "node"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot"
  ]
}
```

All of this works fine and I get the *.js files being generated in my wwwroot folder.

The problem is the generated files use the same `import x from 'lib'` and I think that's causing a problem

```
//Root/wwwroot/js/my_file.js
import Swal from 'sweetalert2';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Chart } from 'chart.js';

...
```

When I try to run everything I get this error in the browser

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "sweetalert2". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

The error will come up for sweetalert2, chart.js and axios.

Any idea where I'm going wrong with this setup?

Thanks!

Comment: If you use baseUrl you specify the start path for the non-relative paths , in this case ./ means where is the tsconfig.json file. Remove it. Furthermore install npm install --save-dev @types/sweetalert2 and set  allowJs:true   e checkJs:true      Restart and try again

Comment: No luck with these changes, I'm getting the same error message, and it looks likes @types/sweetalert is deprecated https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/sweetalert sweetalert provides their own .d.ts file now https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2/blob/main/sweetalert2.d.ts

Comment: yes no need now.  Why do you exclude node_modules folder? Try to remove  baseUrl and exclude setting. the location for import without the trailing comma is node_module by default

Comment: Gave those changes a shot, but still no luck here is the new tsconfig.json 
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "allowJs": true,
    "checkJs":  true,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "outDir": "../js/",
    "lib": [
      "ES5",
      "ES2015",
      "DOM",
      "ScriptHost"
    ],
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "moduleResolution":  "node"
  }
}